# Num Lock on, but the Num Lock LED off

Tags: led, num-lock

I want to have Num Lock on (be able to use the numbers), but have the LED indicator on my keyboard turned off. I don't know what way I want to do this (Autoit, AutoHotKey, C#...).

I found [this link](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/9587-keyboard-led-control-capslocknumlockscrolllock-lights/) and tested the code from evl, but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*Windows-only solution:*

Just add the following remappings to your AutoHotkey script:

```
NumpadIns:: Send 0
NumpadEnd:: Send 1
NumpadDown:: Send 2
NumpadPgDn:: Send 3
NumpadLeft:: Send 4
NumpadClear:: Send 5
NumpadRight:: Send 6
NumpadHome:: Send 7
NumpadUp:: Send 8
NumpadPgUp:: Send 9
NumpadDel:: Send .
```

This way, no matter whether `NumLock` is on or off, pressing the numbers on the numeric keypad will always type the numbers (and `.` instead of `Del`).

Enjoy your light-free keyboard!

PS: You can find the key list on Autohotkey's Help (right click on your script's icon on the taskbar and click `Help`) under `Usage and Syntax`, `Key List (Keyboard, Mouse, Joystick)`.